# Retain dynamic value using global dictionary

Tags: excel, vba

I have an If condition in the cell `B22`. It returns `True` or `False` based on the value of `B1`. Values in cell `B1` are dynamic. I have another `If` condition in `C22` which calls a function `N_50_C22` if the `B22` argument is `True`. I have a requirement where I would need to copy the value of `E1` into `C22` (through the afore mentioned function) when argument from cell `B22` turns `True` only at the first instance. This copied value in `C22` should remain the same irrespective of the subsequent changes in the arguments of `B22`.

I have the below VBA code for function `N_50_C22`.

```
Public Dict_N_50_C22 As New Scripting.Dictionary

Public Function N_50_C22() As Double

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
    Dim High_Break_out As String, ReadCellValue As String

    If Not Dict_N_50_C22.Exists(High_Break_out) Then
        Dict_N_50_C22.Add High_Break_out, ""
    End If

    'Now retrieve the Order Status
    'This will return the value of Key Readcellvalue
    ReadCellValue = Dict_N_50_C22(High_Break_out)

    'If the order status equals the Trans then, we already placed order for that Trans
    'Exit the Function, don't place order again
     If ReadCellValue = "TRUE" Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    'If the Order Status is not equal to Trans then
    'Place the Order
    'Store the Trans as value to the Key TrdSym
    'So that next time it will return the Trans

    'Adding trans to dictionary key
    Dict_N_50_C22.Item(High_Break_out) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UP-MT").Range("B22").Value

    'Place the Order
    N_50_C22 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UP-MT").Range("E1").Value
Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    N_50_C22 = Err.Description
End Function
```

I have problem where this function is returning 0 value for first true statement of `B22`. Would you please resolve this problem.

[image: IMG1]

Comment: Please include your code between code tags using [edit] and not as an image.

Comment: VBA code in Word in image? This is something new...

Comment: have Edit the post. Kindly check.